# What is the main use of transclusion in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I have recently come across transclusion in directives, what is the purpose of having this concept. As far as I know its encapsulation of an object and have 2-way binding possibly. But this can be possible by using '=' in the scope attribute in directive. So whats the big deal about directive?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements

Answer (score 5):

#### Transclude allows :

- To create directives that wrap other elements.
- To clone the same transcluded contents multiple times.
- To re-clone the trancluded contents when an event occurs.

#### ngTransclude and $transclude

- When using the **transclude** option, the element contents are being removed from the DOM during the compile phase.
- The 5th argument of the `linking phase` ( *or $transclude inside directive controllers* ) is a `$transclude function` which allows you to clone the transcluded contents , apply it to a scope and reinsert it to the DOM when you need.
- Angular.js has a built-in directive for simple cases: [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude)

#### I recommend these tutorials:

- [Angular.js - Transclusion basics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjrBTjMvruI)
- [Angular.js - Components and containers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCiAAr87450)

#### Some angular built-in directives (*ng module*) use the `transclude` option:

- [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf)
- [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)
- [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)
- [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

#### In the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> What does **transclude** option do? it makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside.

Actually, that's **not so accurate**, it applies only to the default behavior of angular.js built-in directives and the default behavior of the $transclude function when invoked without scope argument.

The $transclude function allows you to apply any scope you need as an optional first argument:

```
app.directive('example',function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div>example</div>"
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude){
      $transclude(scope, function(clone){
        element.append(clone);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Good answer, real practical uses of transclude.

Answer (score 1):

My main use is to relocate the inner contents of a directive to wherever the `ngTransclude` is inside the template of the directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aQ7SG58g0njSerM8FsNz?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('wrapMe', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span>Stuff before [<b ng-transclude></b>] Stuff after</span>'
  };  
}]);
```